# ODE limits solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I had to find the solutions of this ODE:
$$y'\sin x+y\cos x=1,\quad x\in(0,\pi)$$
which are
$$y_{1}=\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\quad\text{and}\quad y_{2}=\frac{c}{\sin x},c\in\mathbb{R}$$
The exercises asks to prove that one of these solutions has a finite limit when $x\to0$, and another one has finite limit when $x\to\pi$.

I know that
$$\lim_{x\to0}y_{1}=0$$
by L'Hospital. And
$$\lim_{x\to\pi}y_{1}=\infty$$

But, for both, $x$ and $\pi$, I have
$$\lim_{x\to0}y_{2}=\lim_{x\to\pi}y_{2}=\infty$$

So how do I prove what the exercises asks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your $y_2$ is not a solution of the equation. $y_2$ has $y_2'\sin x + y_2\cos x = 0$.

But every 
$$ y_c(x) = \frac{x+c}{\sin x} $$
is a solution. $y_c$ has a finite limit at $x=0$ exactly iff $c= 0$, and then by l'Hospital
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} y_0(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac 1{\cos x} = 1. $$
At $x = \pi$, we have a finite limit iff $c = -\pi$, and there by l'Hopital again
$$ \lim_{x\to \pi} y_{-\pi}(x) = \lim_{x\to \pi} \frac 1{\cos x} = -1. $$
So two solutions with finite limits at $0$ and $\pi$ respectively are 
$$ y_0(x) = \frac{x}{\sin x}, \qquad y_{-\pi}(x) = \frac{x-\pi}{\sin x}. $$